# Angular Material dialog - send data when close

Tags: angular, typescript, dialog

Is there any way to send data from dialog to the "parent" when it's close (even when user clicks outsite or press ESC)?

currently I have a parent whith:

**PARENT:**

```
open(){
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalinvitarComponent, {
      width: '90%',
      maxWidth: '520px'
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result)
    });
}
```

when the modal is closed results get "undefined"

I can send some data from the modal using:

```
this.dialogRef.close(true)
```

then I get "true" in response, but I would like to send data even when the user close the modal clicking outside of the modal or press ESC.

I have a variable inside the modal, and I would like to recive it, no matters the way the user close the modal.

Comment: So does the `afterClosed` Observable not fire then?

Comment: Data is sent when the user closes the dialog with ESC or clicking outside, it's an empty string.

Comment: afterClosed is triggered but i don't know how to send data from the dialog to "result" when the user close the Modal using default options (clicking outside or pressing ESC)

Comment: long after the event, but I've seen some code here that fires ```dialogRef.beforeClosed().subscribe(() => console.log(dialogRef.componentInstance) );``` which might help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the default data, here is how you proceed.

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(
  map(result => !result ? 'Default data' : result),
).subscribe(...);
```

This test will test falsy values (`''`, `undefined`, `null`, `0` ...), and since the default returned value by the dialog is `''`, it will replace it with `'Default data'`.

Comment: The problem is when the user change the data in the modal and after that close the modal clicking outside. I don't recive this change in the parent so the data would be default when it shouldn`t

Comment: That's another issue, completely unrelated to this one. I suggest you create a question with a [mcve].

Comment: In fact is the main issue

Comment: I don't doubt that, what I'm saying is that you didn't say that in your original question, you explained a totally different issue. So, again, consider creating a new question with a [mcve] reproducing this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Today I've encountered the same problem, my workaround: service and rxjs:

```
// service.ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ComunicationService {
  observedEvent$ = new Subject<ISomeInterface>();
  constructor() { }
  eventOcurs(some_object: ISomeInterface) {
    observedEvent$.next(some_object);
  }
}
```

Then in dialog component (ComunicationService is injected as comunicationService) I'm watching for some events and fire important object into observed stream:

```
// dialog-component.ts
this.comunicationService.eventOcurs(some_object);
```

Parent component (ComunicationService is injected as comunicationService) is subscribing for changes:

```
// parent-component.ts
this.comunicationService.observedEvent$.subscribe((some_object) => {
  //some action
})
```

Using services you can follow any change you want.
Benefit of this method is that the parent component is reacting for changes in background, when I close the dialog, all changes are provided in parent component already.